# Suggested edit that is really a new answer?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I've seen a quite a few of [these types of edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6385211) where someone is adding to an answer. In some cases (like this one), I feel that it really should have been posted as a completely separate answer, as the extra info seems to be a different solution, rather than additional information about the one that's being proposed. The edit certainly appears to be helpful (not my area) and it would be a shame to lose the information by rejecting it, and I can't see an appropriate reject reason anyway. So should it be accepted? Or something else? What would YOU do?

Note that I'm not really asking about this specific question, but for this scenario in general.

Comment: "**attempt to reply** This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer."

Comment: @remyabel I did consider this option for the "It should have been written as a comment or an answer." part, but I can't see that he's trying to address the author at all

Comment: @rjdown: That is intended to include "addressing the asker (author of the question)" as well, I believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reject those types of suggestions.

If you really think the edit is really good answer on it's own merit, then you could create your own new answer, click the "community wiki" check box, so you don't get any rep for it, attribute the answer to the suggested edit editor providing a link to that review if you can.